# Laravel sessions are destroyed after login from Google

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, laravel-socialite, laravel-session

I am using Laravel Shopping cart and Laravel Socialite for login, **login works fine** but when the user logs in it deletes his Cart and all other sesshions on the page, do you know how to fix it  ? Thanks

The reason I need this is that the user has the option to complete the order logged in or as a guest, to log in they have the option of using the login form or using the "Login with Google" button
When the user logs in using the login form the** Cart stays**, but only when he uses the **google login so it deletes it**

LOGIN CONTROLLER
`

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');  
    }


          
     // Google login
                public function redirectToGoogle()
                { 
                    return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
                    
                }
            
                // Google callback
                public function handleGoogleCallback()
                {
                 
                   
                   
                    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
                    
                    
                    $this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);
                   
                    // Return home after login
                    return redirect()->route('checkout.index')
                    ->with('toast_success',  'Byli jste úspěšně přihlášeni :)');
                    
                }
            
             
            
             
     protected function _registerOrLoginUser($data)
     {
       
      
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $data->email)->first();
            if (!$user) {
             $user = new User();
             $user->name = $data->name;
             $user->email = $data->email;
             $user->provider_id = $data->id;
             $user->avatar = $data->avatar;
             $user->save();
         }
        
         Auth::login($user);
        
         
     }
    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        session()->put('previousUrl', url()->previous());

        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

`

Otherwise if I try to put Cart into collection (collect(session()->pull('cart')) before the login is processed, it deletes that too, I tried session regenerate and nothing works either.
So far it seems to me that after login the page gets a completely "new indentity" ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fact the session ID gets regenerated when you call the function `$this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);`

You could try storing the cart session in a collection or array before that function is called, and then afterwards try to repopulate the session using that collection/array after `$this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);`

Comment: i tried `dd(session()->get('cart'));` before `$this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);` to see if there was anything and it returns null, and on collection it return empty collection ://